# Read from MongoDB into sklearn (scikit-learn)

Tags: mongodb, scikit-learn

Apologies if this has been asked, but I have looked here and elsewhere on the web for an answer and nothing has been forthcoming.

The basic examples of using sklearn are either reading from a prepared sklearn dataset into memory, or reading from a file such as a .csv into memory and then processing. Can someone kindly provide an equivalent example for reading database data into sklearn for processing, preferably MongoDB, but I will take what I can get at this point. I have been struggling with this for a little while now.

I can post what I have done so far, but I don't think it will help. Thanks for any help/advice/pointers.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [sklearn.feature_extraction](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html)?

Comment: pymongo returns data in a dictionary format, so you could use that in conjunction with feature_extraction, as philipvr has mentioned. mongo also has the [mongoexport](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongoexport/) function which will allow you to dump csv, assuming your data are in a flat format, compatible with csv.

Comment: Thanks a lot both. I had come across that page before (shown by philipvr), but not fully understood it. Looking at it again, it does make a bit more sense now. Regarding the CSV dumping. I was hoping to dispense with CSV and read straight in to sklearn data structures. I did also come across a segment in a book last night with a definitive answer on how to read into a DataFrame. The missing piece for that was still how to munge it into a format suitable for sklearn, but it looks like the sklearn.feature_extraction should do the trick. Thanks again.

Comment: Or try a `sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer`.